# Who or what is Mr. Mighty?

Tags: spider-man, religion, marvel, folklore, spider-verse

In the comic *Spider-Verse #2*, one of the tales follows Anansi. I'm vaguely familiar with Anansi, as an African trickster god, and was able to find some information on [Shango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Shango), who appeared in the story. However, I can't find information on Mr. Mighty, the last character in the story. I assume they're based on an existing character from the same religions and folktales as Anansi and Shango.

Who is Mr. Mighty, and what is their religious original source character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mr Mighty is a minor character in the original [Anansi source stories](http://www.sacred-texts.com/afr/jas/jas004.htm), specifically story #4; "Tiger's Sheep Suit".

Mr Mighty is characterised as a rich and powerful (but stupid) land-owner with a substantial farmholding. Anansi works for him and gradually steals all of his sheep, then frames his friend Tiger as the thief, collecting both the reward for the thief's capture as well as the hand of the land-owner's daughter:

> "*Anansi was a head-man for a man by the name of Mr. Mighty, who
>   employed Anansi for the purpose of minding some sheep. The sheep
>   numbered about two thousand. And from the first day Anansi took over
>   the sheep, the man began to miss one. An' he steal them until he leave
>   only one. Well, Mr. Mighty would like to find out how the sheep go. He
>   say to Anansi he would give his best daughter and two hundred pound to
>   find out how the sheep go.*
>
> *Anansi say the best way to find it out is to make a ball. Anansi have a friend name of Tiger, call him 'Brar Tiger'. He went to Tiger an'
>   tell him Mr. Mighty promise to give his daughter an' two hundred pound to whomsoever tell how the sheep go.*
>
> ... [later at the ball]
>
> *Mr. Mighty got right up an' said to Tiger, "Yes, that is the man what steal all my sheep!" Tiger say, "No!!" Anansi say, "Yes, that is the
>   man what steal all the sheep, an' I an' that man eatin' an' I didn't
>   know that man was such a t'ief!" An' Tiger was arrested an' got ten
>   years in prison, an' Anansi get the two hundred pounds an' the best
>   daughter to marry to.*

Comment: For the record, Anansi seems a great friend to have :-(